# SQL Server: Return only unique values per group(not distinct)(not one of each value)

Tags: sql-server

I need to return one unique value per group of values in one column, like the below example

```
    COL 1   | COL 2 
    1   |A  
    1   |A  
    2   |B
    2   |C
    2   |C
    3   |A
    3   |B
    3   |D
    3   |D
```

Return:

```
    COL 1   | COL 2 
    2   |B
    3   |A
    3   |B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an aggregate function `COUNT()` so you can filter unique row.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: awesome, that's a great tool.